# Write C# class manually that confirm to XSD Schema (xs:schema) layout?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, schema, .net-core

In Visual Studio, I used xsd.exe to generate C# classes.  Unfortunately, it doesn't work cuz the C# class are missing lot of stuff that XSD file have.

So, I decided to write C# class manually.  That's when I start having trouble finding documentation that would show me how.  Nobody use XML now anymore so I'm stuck with a 15 years old XSD files that haven't been updated which is why I have to write C# class manually.

Can anyone point me to examples or documentation on how to find the proper objects I should use to make this happen.

For starter, the `XmlRoot` attribute below - how do I add `targetNamespace` attribute.  The example below doesn't work cuz it is incorrect object/attribute which is why I'm asking for direction to point me to the right direction.  The XSD file is almost 7,000 lines long and that create a challenge to write C# class manually.

Edited: I just wrote the script that would serialize this C# class into XML and validate it against the XSD file.  All I have to do is to keep building the C# class.

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Foo.RouteOne
{
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://www.openapplications.org/oagis")]
    public class Process
    {
    }
}
```

[Edited - 08/25/2017] - We decided to go with string builder to build XML data because we still struggling with it 3 weeks later.  We had lost lot of valuable time trying to make this work.

Comment: May I recommend a different approach? You can generate an XSD file from C# classes. Do so (with the ones automatically created), then compare them with your target XSD file. You should be able to make minor modifications to your classes based on the differences between the desired and actual output.

Comment: The 3rd party company gave us 5 xsd files and that's it.  No programming language (C#) source code came with it.  :-/   I had written .NET script that would serialize the C# class into xml and validate the XML against the XSD to get started.  In answer to your comment, I have the failed C# class for comparison to the new C# class I'm writing.

Comment: I think I understand. What I'm suggesting is that you have two XSD files (or rather, two sets). 1 set was given by the company. The other can be created by using the automated XSD->Class tool, then using the Class->XSD tool on that. You can compare the two sets of XSD files and modify the auto-generated class until it is generating the right XSD file. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes it does now.  The thing I'm stuck on is finding the documentation for list of all XML objects that I can use when writing C# file.

Comment: Are you looking for [Attributes That Control XML Serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/serialization/attributes-that-control-xml-serialization) and/or [Controlling XML Serialization Using Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/serialization/controlling-xml-serialization-using-attributes)?

Comment: There's also [Introducing XML Serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/serialization/introducing-xml-serialization)... err, Microsoft's doc link is broken, here's the old version: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh(v=vs.100).aspx